# Triggered lambda by SQS, tries to requeue but the lambda it's not triggered

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda that is triggered by a SQS message, my problem is that, the processing of the message fails for some reason, this message should be requeued.

Now i had been debugging but still no idea why this happens:
let's suppose i send a SQS message and it fails, the lambda will try to requeue to the same SQS queue, but right here is where i have my problem: according to the logs, the message is sent but the same lambda it's not being triggered, i don't see the SQS message in the queue either.

```
 # code for processing the message, we call some API and we get the response

 if response.status_code not in [200, 201] and  body["retryTime"] <= 5:
            # if the API response didn't went ok
            # update the number of tries
            body["retryTime"] += 1
            # we resend message to be requeued
            sqs_response = upload_to_sqs_fifo(
                sqs,
                json.dumps(body),
                message_attributes,
                message_deduplication_id,
                message_group_id,
            )

        elif response.status_code not in [200, 201] and  body["retryTime"] > 5:
            exception_message = "Maximum tries to re-send SQS message"

            raise Exception(exception_message)
```

I never see the message of 'Maximum tries to res-send SQS message', even i on purpose return a different response code 200 or 201.

The SQS is FIFO type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the lambda isn't being invoked at all. Assuming the EventSourceMapping between the queue and the lambda has been configured correctly, it could be a permissions issue.

Make sure the role assigned to the lambda has the **AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole** policy attached. This will give the lambda permission to poll the queue.

Comment: If the lambda isn't invoked at all, what about the SQS message? it shouldn't be visible in the queue?

Comment: I would think that if the lambda is not being invoked...(meaning, the queue is not being polled by the lambda), then the message would remain on the queue. I'm assuming you have confirmed that the message is arriving in the queue correctly. If this isn't the case, disable the lambda trigger and makes sure the message is arriving as expected first.